# Examples of theorems misapplied to non-mathematical contexts

Tags: ho.history-overview, big-list, applied-mathematics, popularization

For something I'm writing -- I'm interested in examples of bad arguments which involve the application of mathematical theorems in non-mathematical contexts.  E.G. folks who make theological arguments based on (what they take to be) Godel's theorem, or Bayesian arguments for creationism.  (If necessary I'm willing to extend the net to physics, to include bad applications of the second law of thermodynamics or the Uncertainty Principle, if you know any really amusing ones.)

Comment: Do you want examples where they use the theorem correctly, but the real-world context violates one of the assumptions (e.g., ignoring that the Earth is not thermodynamically a closed system), or that they just misunderstand the theorem itself?

Comment: Either is fine!

Comment: Does "applying the Banach-Tarski paradox to an orange" qualify?

Comment: Do you have standards for attribution, e.g., the argument should be published somewhere, or is word-of-mouth fair game?

Comment: This is purely exploratory, so use the most expansive standards of anything you think might fit.

Comment: Rather than Gödel's incompleteness theorem applied to theological arguments, there is Gödel's ontological proof of the existence of God (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gödel's_ontological_proof), which is more likely to be misapplied...

Comment: I feel like most people misapply Godel's incompleteness theorem.

Comment: Gödel's work, together with that of Church and Turing and others, does show, however, that much philosophy and theology (even stuff which is supposed to be respectable) misconceives the relationship between truth, provability, possibility, rationality, knowledge and reality.

Comment: Perhaps it was my being ignorant of algebraic topology as a kid, but splitting my sandwich with my brother did not seem to be fair!

Comment: Great thread.  I think the fundamental fallacies behind this phenomenon are misinterpretation of terms, and thinking that real-world situations are part of a formal system.  Approximations are often effectively used, but to conclude that your result applies you have to demonstrate with HIGH confidence that your approximation is sufficiently accurate.


Comment: Assume average life expectancy and use Secretary Problem to "guess" the best moment (or day, or whatever) of one's life.

Comment: @BenjaminDickman Looks OK if you restrict it to a fixed span of 5 years within which your conditions are stable. My favorite example is Pascal' wager. First, it has been created by a mathematician (and not a second rate one!), second, the minimax decision strategy is pretty widespread and makes sense, third, there seems to be no one who didn't try some form of it to convince an opponent (yeah, if you drive at 70 mph in this blizzard and don't crash, we'll come in time for the dinner, but think of what happens if you do!), forth, even Wikipedia fails to explain what exactly is wrong with it.

Answer (score 141):

A tragic example of this is the case [People v. Collins](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/People_v._Collins), in which a prosecutor asked a mathematician (as an expert witness) a question of the form, "assuming these events are independent, what is the probability that...". The events were obviously not independent, things like "drives a convertible", "has a caucasian girlfriend", "girlfriend has blond hair", and some others. The mathematician answered the misleading question correctly (assuming independence), and the defendant went to jail. The California Supreme Court later overturned the verdict, [in a decision](http://scholar.google.com/scholar_case?case=2393563144534950884) that shows a surprisingly solid understanding of probability.

This case could be required reading (the supreme court decision, anyway) in any introduction to probability course. It has counting, independence, and conditional probability all involved in a fundamental way.

Comment: And one of the judges dissented?!

Comment: Very interesting! I'd heard of the case before, but I never knew the verdict was overturned.

Arguably, the best-known (and most awful) example of this kind of thing is the Sally Clark case: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sally_Clark. The Royal Statistical Society wrote a very good public statement about it. The statement is posted on the RSS web site, but unfortunately the link seems to be broken.

Comment: From the Supreme Court's decision: "Mathematics, a veritable sorcerer in our computerized society, while assisting the trier of fact in the search for truth, must not cast a spell over him."

Comment: Eric, maybe you mean 1-(1-1/10000)^20000 ?

Comment: It is worth looking at the multiple testing example under the Prosecutor's Fallacy:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prosecutor%27s_fallacy#Examples_of_prosecutor.27s_fallacies 
This explains another way that data in the court room can be misinterpreted. 

Answer (score 98):

Here are some examples, ranging from the comical to the debatable.

**Comical**: Pretty much any mention of mathematics in Jacques Lacan. To give you an idea, here is a typical passage:

> This diagram [the Möbius strip] can be considered the basis of a sort of essential inscription at the origin, in the knot which constitutes the subject. This goes much further than you may think at first, because you can search for the sort of surface able to receive such inscriptions. You can perhaps see that the sphere, that old symbol for totality, is unsuitable. A torus, a Klein bottle, a cross-cut surface, are able to receive such a cut. **And this diversity is very important as it explains many things about the structure of mental disease**. If one can symbolize the subject by this fundamental cut, in the same way one can show that a cut on a torus corresponds to the neurotic subject, and on a cross-cut surface to another sort of mental disease. [Lacan (1970), pp. 192-193]

And here's another one:

> Thus, by calculating that signification according to the algebraic method used here, namely $$\frac{S(\text{Signifier})}{s(\text{signified})} = s(\text{the statement})$$ with $S=(-1)$ produces $s=\sqrt{-1}$[...]**Thus the erectile organ comes to symbolize the place of jouissance, not in itself, or even in the form of an image, but as a part lacking in the desired image: that is why it is equivalent to the  of the signification produced above, of the jouissance that it restores by the coefficient of its statement to the function of the lack of signifier -1**. [Lacan (1971); seminar held in 1960.]

**Interesting/Rigorous but still quite a stretch**: The work of Alain Badiou on set theory, although more rigorous and advanced, also provides a very good resource for misapplications of formal mathematics in order to draw non-mathematical conclusions, cf. especially *Being and Event* which is his magnum opus, in which he uses set theory to support the tagline that 'Mathematics is Ontology'. Unlike Lacan, Badiou at least knows his stuff when it comes to the statement and development of formal results. That said, his interpretations and conclusions are often huge stretches.

Here's a related MO post on Badiou:

[Badiou and Mathematics](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/8285/badiou-and-mathematics)

**Interesting/Philosophy**: I don't know if you'd call these misapplications, but they are certainly attempts to use formal results to draw philosophical conclusions that are not in any formal way entailed by those results. Here are some examples:

- Michael Dummett on how Godel Incompleteness might/might not threaten the thesis that meaning is use (philosophical anti-realism):

The philosophical significance of Gödel's theorem, M Dummett - Ratio, 1963

- Hilary Putnam on how the Lowenheim-Skolem Theorem proves that reference is underdetermined by all possible theoretical or operation constraints (i.e. that the meaning of our mathematical vocabulary can never be accurately understood in order to *fix* an intended model):

http://www.jstor.org/stable/2273415

Pretty much anything philosophical that has been written about the so-called Skolem Paradox involves formal-to-informal entailments.

- Roger Penrose in *The Emperor's New Mind* again using Godel to draw conclusions about consciousness and mechanism

Comment: Great answer -- and your mention of Lacan reminds me that, while it's not quite about a THOEOREM, the Lang-Huntington affair is certainly a good example of what I'm looking for!



Comment: Actually, more on the debatable side, especially because the lack of precision keeps things open to an interpretations!

Comment: Lacan featured prominently in Sokal's hoax.

Comment: To add to the list, something that sounds a lot like a misapplication to me is the interpretation of "every sufficiently nontrivial class of languages is unlearnable" as "we must have a built-in natural grammar in our brains". And I think it appeared here on MO. But I'm not sure, which is why I am not posting it as an answer. It just seems to me that "unlearnable" doesn't translate as "unlearnable" into reality, but rather as "we can never be 100% sure that we speak the same language as the others rather than falling victim to an epically complicated misunderstanding". ...

Comment: ... Given how frequent misunderstanding of words and even whole passages of text are, I would not be *too* surprised if one day somebody manages to misunderstand a whole language.

Comment: I've looked at Badiou's work and I'd put it in your third category of "Interesting/Philosophy."  These don't strike me as misapplications.  It sounds to me that you're tacitly assuming that it is always illegitimate to use formal results to support a philosophical thesis unless the formal results *formally* entail the thesis, but this is itself a controversial philosophical stance.  I'd reserve the term "misapplication" for situations where the applier misunderstands the mathematical result, or gets the technical details wrong, or claims that something follows formally when it doesn't.

Comment: Timothy crystallizes the point that I had in mind when I said "more on the debatable side". 

Comment: One of my collegues, Lucien Guillou, told me that he was asked to give lessons in topology, especially knot theory, to psychanalysts of 
the Lacanian sort. One of the reason for their interest was the Borromean rings which they took for a illustration of the link between body, spirit and soul. Take one out and the remaining two fall apart.

Comment: My dissertation supervisor (in algebraic geometry) also mentioned the Borromean rings when I told him that I am interested in Philosophy - his way of saying "Is THIS what you're interested in?" 

Comment: I'd just like to note that Douglas Hofstadter, *Gödel, Escher, Bach* refutes arguments similar to Penrose's that try to use Gödel's theorem to prove that a human is computationally more powerful than a computer – Penrose's book wasn't published yet at that time so he doesn't refer to it.  (I must note though that Penrose does not try to present his ideas as an indisputable proof in the mathematical sense, only as his opinion.)  Hofstadter's book, however, later applies mathematical logic theorems for other questionable analogies.  

Comment: I have seen an example (cant find the reference, unfortunately) where a mathematical analogy (similarity to a fractal), is used to explain the movement of a librarian. This was published in social sciences, and the author had very little mathematical knowledge, judging from the text. It seems like non-mathematician finds it tempting to (mostly wronglgy) compare something in the real world with an abstract mathematical notion, in order to intimidate the reader. I see no other reason why one would like to take something simple, and compare to something complicated.

Comment: You cannot criticize Lacan based on a few excerpts with some formulae and no knowledge of Lacan! You are showing your own ignorance.

Comment: It is fairly off-topic because Lacan never use mathematical formalism, in its proper sense, to justify psychoanalytical properties. For instance he claims that demand - need = desire, though when he explains what desire is it is certainly not in its exact sense a subtraction. That is, the math is just an analogy. A lot of Lacanians are nutcases, but this answer is symptomatic to why mathematicians need to go beyond math sometimes.

Answer (score 84):

My favourite in this direction is an [application of Noether's theorem to public relations](http://www.informaworld.com/index/785832347.pdf): Sha, "Noether's Theorem: The Science of Symmetry and the Law of Conservation", J. Public Relations Research, 16 (2004) 391-416.

I quote from the abstract:

> Noether's Theorem shows that
>   symmetry-or change-can only exist
>   simultaneously with conservation or
>   invariance. For public relations, the
>   implication is that an organization
>   can behave "symmetrically" while
>   maintaining certain beliefs,
>   principles, or purposes that will
>   never be relinquished. A case study of
>   the Democratic Progressive Party (DPP)
>   on Taiwan using participant
>   observation (13 months), qualitative
>   interviews (n = 22), and a
>   quantitative survey (n = 166; response
>   rate = 28.77%) showed that the
>   organization exhibited symmetry by
>   reaching out to external publics,
>   engaging in dialogue with them, and
>   expressing openness regarding Taiwan
>   independence. Simultaneously, the
>   party conserved its interests in
>   gaining power and establishing an
>   independent Taiwan. Recent electoral
>   victories of the DPP suggest the
>   effectiveness of symmetry-conservation
>   for public relations practice.

Comment: This is amazing.  I find it hard to believe it's not a joke, but the paper actually seems to have been cited a few times, with no indication that it is being read as anything other than at least a serious analogy with physics (for example, in "New media and public relations" by Sandra Duhé; see http://books.google.com/books?id=n6hyFnSRkEwC&pg=PA8).

Comment: I agree, this "application" is extremely laughable.  I was expecting a million answers about Godel's theorems, but Noether's theorem applied to public relations?  *grooooaaaaaan.....*  I guess the problem is in thinking that our definition of "symmetry" is the same as their definition of "symmetry"

Comment: From Bey-Ling Sha's biography at San Diego State University:

"Dr. Sha's primary research program combines theories of mathematical physics with public relations scholarship. Her other research areas include international public relations, activism, cultural identity, gender, and health communication. Her research has been published in Journal of Public Relations Research, Public Relations Review, and Journal of Promotion Management, as well as various book chapters."

Needless to say, she has a PhD in mass communication, not mathematical physics.

Comment: This is actually very typical for social sciences courses. I've seen a number of required books with titles like "quantum leadership" that start by misquoting physics or math and then pretend to apply the misquoted concepts.

Answer (score 46):

A couple of misapplications of physics come to mind:

Conservation of angular momentum does not mean what people think it means. If you have an object spinning on a flat surface, it can't turn around without outside forces, right? Wrong, the [rattleback](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rattleback) toy does this ([video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LmEf7aIhpF8)).

The [Coriolis effect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coriolis_effect) is real, but the idea that this has something to do with the direction water spins down the drain is a [false](http://www.ems.psu.edu/~fraser/Bad/BadCoriolis.html) [urban legend](http://www.snopes.com/science/coriolis.asp).

Comment: That's neat. Thanks for the link to the rattleback.

Comment: Evidently I don't understand conservation of angular momentum. I am very confused.

Comment: Well, perhaps my presentation was misleading. Rolling is complicated, and there is a transfer of angular momentum from the rattleback to the surface. 

Comment: On a related note, this reminds of R. Montgomery's paper "On the Gauge Theory of a Falling Cat", which use some fairly high powered mathematics to show how it is possible for a falling object (ie a cat) to spin around and reorient itself without acting on any outside forces.  The same technique is actually used in satellites to reposition themselves in outer space! (Link to PDF: http://count.ucsc.edu/~rmont/papers/cat.PDF )

Comment: I have been taught that friction and normal reaction are both *outside* force and that the sum of one vertical vector and one horizontal is just anything you want, so if applied together away from the center of gravity, these two can create any torque you fancy. Of course, the difficulty is in making them to coordinate in an interesting way, but that has little to do with any conservation laws.

Answer (score 46):

This is not an answer. Just a very long comment. Mostly I am stunned by the answers given.

(1) I'm surprised to see Lacan featured as the main example. What I see in these quotes is an attempt to formalise human condition. Is it laughable? Yes! But no more that 16th century physics and widely taken as such. I'm pretty sure  99,9% of the human population never heard of Lacan and was never affected by his thoughts on maths in any way.

(2) If I was in the audience for a talk on "Theorems misapplied to non-mathematical contexts" I'd selfishly want to see examples that affected me or someone I know. Amazingly, none of the answers given until now mentionned the field of ECONOMICS. Some people in this field are passing opinions (often political) for mathematical facts every day and this translates into policies that have influence on the lives of millions (if not billions) of people.

Just an example. When the subprime mortgage buble exploded, we heard most banks and insurance companies were shocked because "their experts(*) said the price of houses couldn't go down everywhere in the US at the same time". In fancier terms, it was widely believed that the use of Collateralized Debt Obligations (CDO) and Credit Default Swaps (CDS) were minimizing the risk of default while it was actually just spreading and increasing it. I am very ignorant in mathematical finance but I'd like someone to try and explain to me which theorems that was based on. I'm pretty sure this should go straight to the top of the list.

(*) I used the word "experts" as a generic word for "economists and mathematicians employed by financial institutions".

Comment: The "experts" also more or less assumed that mortgage failures were events independent from each other...

Comment: Not sure where you heard that from, but I've never heard of someone in credit products assuming defaults are uncorrelated.  

But I feel this is getting off-topic.  People build models based on assumptions that approximate reality, sometimes the assumptions are good and sometimes not.  It would be unfair to say that is misapplying math--if anything, math is the science of making conclusions from assumptions!  I don't think people claimed to have theorems saying mortgage delinquencies couldn't double, but they might have had models assigning 0 probability to that due to the assumptions.

Comment: @Luke: I suggest you try to explain to your Greek friends the subtle distinction you drew in the last sentence of your comment. You know, like, in terms of actual consequences for their real lifes...

Comment: But Didier Piau, while it might be true that the distinction Luke Gustafson makes does not have much practical influence, I think it *does* make quite a difference for the *question at hand*. Consider something else and made up: If a bridge colapses because a mathematician used the wrong PDE or an illsuited solver or whatever to compute the static it is on-topic here, if the math. was told the max load will be 1000 tons and s/he should compute with a marging of safety for 1200 t. but then for some reason there where 1500 t. on that bridge and it collapsed then it seems off-topic here.  

Comment: Here is an exposition paper that discusses the sensitivity of the risk measures being used to slight misspecification of the correlation of financial assets: https://www.aeaweb.org/articles?id=10.1257/jep.23.1.3

Comment: @LukeGustafson: I have only a very rough sense of this, but my impression is that one issue was basically a misapplication of the Central Limit Theorem.  It was clear to everyone that defaults were not independent, yet they continued to assume that the aggregate amount would follow a Gaussian distribution, which predicted a much lower probability of a large total than would have been mathematically justified.  Shortly thereafter, the mathematical finance world got a lot more interested in heavy-tailed distributions and stable limit laws...

Comment: I agree with the poster that it would be really great if someone with more direct knowledge could write something.

Comment: @LukeGustafson I do not know much about that story with subprime mortgage crisis, but in my impression, "experts in economics" never formulate their declarations as conditional statements. Perhaps in US the situation is different, but in Russia I never heard them saying: "Assuming that... we recommend.... But attention, this is only our assumption! We did not check it! There is a possibility that we are not right, and in this case the corollaries will be the following:..." Nothing like this. They say very different things: "according to our science, you should do this and this!"

Comment: Don't you think this is a misapplication of mathematics?

Comment: In Soviet times, they were referring to their wonderful science, saying without any doubts, that it was necessary to build communism. None of them talked about unverified hypotheses. When, at the cost of millions of lives, it became clear that these hypotheses were wrong, they in the same way, absolutely without a doubt, began to say that it was necessary to distribute property to several people, and a civilized life would be built. In this way, they brought Russia back to tsarist times, but they still have no doubts that everything was done according to science.

Comment: "I am very ignorant in mathematical finance but I'd like someone to try and explain to me which theorems that was based on."  There were never any theorems that said housing prices couldn't go down. I downvote because you haven't given one concrete example of a theorem which  has been misapplied.

Answer (score 35):

There are very many examples of the misuse of probability arguments in legal cases.  See e.g.  [the Prosecutor's fallacy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prosecutor%27s_fallacy).

Comment: So there is no more chance than one in a million that person has these characteristics - and a person of this kind committed the crime. So it must be the person in front of you, how could it possibly be anyone else?

But the population of the nation is 60 million. What distinguishes this person from the other 59 (on average) who have the same profile?

Answer (score 33):

As you mentioned, an often misapplied mathematical statement is [Heisenberg's uncertainty principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncertainty_principle), which for me, as a reader of Chriss-Ginzburg, is the purely mathematical statement that any subvariety of classical phase space ($\mathrm{Specm}(\mathrm{gr}A)$) that arises from a noncommutative system of equations (an ideal in A) is coisotropic. The Encyclopedia of Science and Religion states:

> There has also been an interest in using quantum uncertainty, and the breakdown of rigid determinism that it ensures, to defend the concept of free will and to provide a channel for divine action in the world in the face of unbreakable laws of nature.

I've come across this often in religious discourse- the claim that the uncertainty principle states that "everything is uncertain" and that therefore the laws of nature are subject to the decisions of G-d. I've heard it freely confused with the "law of relativity", which apparently states that "everything is relative".
Moreover, some anthropologists cite Heisenberg's uncertainty principle [as follows](http://lawsoflife.co.uk/heisenbergs-uncertainty-principle/):

> In social situations, too, the simple presence of an observer - an anthropologist at a tribal ceremony, a news reporter at a schoolboard meeting, or a TV camera in a courtroom - generally influences the course of events to some uncertain degree as they are recorded. The distortion that results from measurement or observation is called the Heisenberg Effect as in “No one does or can do the same thing on stage that he does unobserved...”

Comment: This answer does not make it obvious, to me, that the uncertainty principle cannot be applied to religion in the way suggested.  I would guess that, at least, most attempts to make this application are flawed, but the surely the physically interpreted version, not the abstract mathematical one, is the uncertainty principle in question?

Comment: I don't see why $\Delta x \Delta p \geq \frac{\hbar}{2}$ would have any more application to religion that the formulation which I gave... I would doubt that most non-scientists are familiar with either formulation, nor do they mean either formulation when they cite it (although it would be entertaining if they did). Rather, it's turned into "everything is uncertain" or "the presence of an observer influences what is being observed".

Comment: Daniel, I voted down this answer for two reasons: (1)
As Charles tried to tell you, your first example is, *at best*, an example of misuse of a *physical*, not mathematical *result*, and therefore does n;t answer the question as asked. (2) But actually, this is not a misuse at all, since the question of determinism is
relevant to the old philosophical/theological debate on free will.
Indeed, for centuries, the main argument *against* free will was
based on the syllogism "if the world is deterministic, free will is impossible", which was roughly justified as follows: "if the present state...

Comment: ...of the world determines the future state, there is nothing the will can change about the future". This line of reasoning was used
by both scientific and religious people, with the determinism of Newton's law of physics as one of the way to justify that the world is indeed determinism. Now the fact that the formulation of Quantum Mechanics is not deterministic surely undermines this argument.
 

Comment: The uncertainty principle doesn't have anything to do with determinism (or the lack thereof)! It just implies our inability to *measure* with arbitrary accuracy two quantities at the same time. Quantum mechanics of course "non deterministic", but non-determinism is built into the theory: it is not a consequence of the uncertainty principle.

Comment: PS Quantum evolution is pretty deterministic.

Comment: Where can one read about this general a version of the unicertainty principle? I know of it in terms of commutators of matrices, not in terms of "gr" (the grassmanian?)

Answer (score 33):

"Therefore, socialist economy is impossible, in every sense of the word."

Robert Murphy comes to this conclusion in [*Cantor’s Diagonal Argument: An Extension to the Socialist Calculation Debate*](http://mises.org/journals/qjae/pdf/qjae9_2_1.pdf).$^1$

The debate is over whether a Central Planning Board can, even in theory, correctly price goods and services, as it is assumed a market economy can. Socialists such as Dickinson argued that a market economy can, in principle, be simulated by the Board, even if it means solving a large system of simultaneous equations. Hayek, on behalf of the Austrians, agreed, yet maintained the number of equations—presumably one for each product and potential product—is clearly too large in practice. Both sides claimed victory.

In the cited article, the author takes the ball from Hayek and carries it across the goal line: after a decent three-page explanation of the diagonal argument, Murphy concludes the Planning Board’s task would not merely be impractical, but fully impossible because of the requirement to publish an uncountably infinite list of prices.

I suppose if one started with the assumption there are (at least) countably infinite number of products/services $p_1, p_2, \dots$ and also agreed that any possible subset of these products is again a product itself, the price of which is not necessarily the sum of the component prices (let’s ignore issues of convergence!), then one could conclude using Cantor’s Theorem ($2^S>S$) there are an uncountable number of products the Board must “list”. But I’m not sure why, if we take the listing process literally, it matters how large the infinity is.

$^1$THE QUARTERLY JOURNAL OF AUSTRIAN ECONOMICS VOL. 9, NO. 2 (SUMMER 2006): 3–11

Comment: The key thing about the market is that nobody needs to know all the money prices but they are consistent (each contains information about all) or there is a thermostat negative feedback that rapidly converges to such a state. Hayek and especially his opponents, in particular, were wrong regarding solving market simultaneous equations absent an unbiased common medium of exchange. Behaviorally value is known to be not a function, an invariant in the nonclosed category of all partially ordered sets of words monotonically transformed. And factors of production are not in the domain of ...

Comment: this ordering. They don't satisfy wants directly and values of possibly consumed goods correspond to concrete wants one to one satisfied or anticipated to be satisfied. Without a perfectly liquid consumption good with an unbiased price in each goods exchange pair it is present and relative scarcity being used to map quantities of it to factors of production, no value proxy for factors of production exists and they cannot be valued. In which case costs exist but are unknown. The equations to solve would be unknown. Which is a problem, for ends don't justify means, foregone ends (costs) exist.

Comment: If values of factors of production are unknown, they cannot be compared with values of consumed goods by anybody, and which quantities of each are to be produced to cause least dissatisfaction, given that resources are insufficient to produce arbitrary quantities of each all at once, becomes unknown and unknowable. Listed prices would be correct only be accident if ever. Assuming an unbiased money exists (so it's not a socialist economy) the solving of equations explicitly is complicated ...

Comment: by the fact that, as Milne (1949) showed, these types of equations are typically unstable, a small change of parameters leads to orders of magnitude different solutions. Which means that if measurement or estimation errors occur, the validity of solutions cannot be confirmed. An calculated price due mostly to error in measuring conditions cannot be distinguished from a solution of completely different conditions. The reason the linked authors thought it matters how large infinity is, I guess, because perhaps they imagined Russell-type hypercomputers possibly doing the calculations?

Comment: The article has a problem: there are no calculations to solve in a socialist economy. The authors argue apparently that socialist economies cannot exist because they could never make sufficiently many arbitrary guesses and list them all even with a hypercomputer, and so cannot be called socialist economies: they didn't plan absolutely everything, implying no socialist economies can exist. Which is true but trivially so. One defines socialisms as planned almost everywhere. Socialist economies have a problem because they arbitrarily guess their productions, not a problem listing their guesses.

Answer (score 30):

[This recent article](http://www.ams.org/notices/201409/rnoti-p1024.pdf) is a striking example of debunking 
a misuse of mathematics in social sciences. In short, some diversity scholars had claimed to prove a "theorem" that diverse groups of less able individuals outperform uniform groups of more able ones. Upon examination, it turns out that the theorem is

- wrong;
- trivial and contentless if corrected;
- has assumptions that make it irrelevant for applications, in particular, they are not met in the numerical experiment featured in the paper to illustrate the theorem.

Remarkably, the authors use an expression "for any probability measure on (a finite set) $\Phi$ with full support, (something holds) with probability one", instead of saying that it holds for every element of $\Phi$.

It seems to be a widely accepted result, published in PNAS with about 500 citations in Google Scholar.

Answer (score 28):

The original question, and several of the answers, refer to misuse of Godel's work, but with very few specific citations. For these, I would suggest Torkel Franzen's book, Godel's Theorem: An Incomplete Guide to its Use and Abuse.

Comment: Oh yeah!  Should have said I have Franzen's book at hand.  I recommend it.

Comment: Franzen's book is excellent and a quick read: it is not an exhaustive list of the abuses in questions (or it would be longer!) but it does cover some common misconceptions and high profile cases (e.g. Penrose). More importantly, it does an excellent job of going straight to the problem, and makes the subtleties of the technique quite accessible to a non-logician but mathematically sophisticated reader.

Comment: I was more referring to misuse in conversation with artsy people who are in love with "What the Bleep do we know?"

Comment: Is the book incomplete as a consequence of Godel's theorem?

Comment: @AsafKaragila In the Preface, Franzén writes, "For any remaining instances of incompleteness or inconsistency in the book, I consider myself entirely blameless, since after all, Gödel proved that any book on the incompleteness theorem must be incomplete or inconsistent. Well, maybe not."

Answer (score 23):

[Alan Sokal and Jean Bricmont's book](http://books.google.com/books?id=SM8zAd3z3ugC&printsec=frontcover&dq=alan+sokal&hl=en&ei=6tikTenNEYf6sAPnqun5DA&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=1&ved=0CCgQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q&f=false%20''Book'') deserves some mention if we are talking about misuse of theorems.

Answer (score 23):

The "No free lunch" (NFL) theorem from mathematical optimization was used by William Dembski to disprove Darwinian theory of evolution. (The relevance of NFL's theorem  to evolution was proposed  earlier by Stuart Kauffman.)

Olle Haggstrom wrote a [paper](http://www.math.chalmers.se/~olleh/Dembski_2.pdf) debunking Dembski's argument.  (Here is an [early version](http://www.math.chalmers.se/~olleh/Dembski.pdf) with stronger rhetorics.)

Answer (score 19):

Arrow's theorem is often glossed as "there is no good voting system".

Press' paper [Strong profiling is not mathematically optimal for discovering rare malfeasors](http://www.pnas.org/content/early/2009/02/02/0813202106.abstract) has been misinterpreted by the popular press as a mathematical endorsement of certain politics, though that's perhaps due in part to the intentional framing of the problem by Press.

Goedel's theorem is misapplied arguably more than it is used properly.

Comment: How exactly is that a missapplication of Arrow's theorem? It is certainly a valid interpretation.

Comment: @Michael: I haven't time to go into specifics at the moment, but a much better gloss of Arrow's theorem is "IIA is an unreasonable condition in ordinal voting systems"; consider the 3-voter case and any majoritarian system.

Answer (score 17):

This isn't exactly what you asked for, but I find it so amusing I could not resist.

The [Indiana $\pi$ bill](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indiana_Pi_Bill), when they almost passed a bill claiming that $\pi=3.2$, in order to be able to square the circle.

Unbelievable.

Comment: The bill did not say pi is 3.2, it was actually far too incomprehensible to infer any specific value of pi.

Comment: One interpretation I read was pi = 9.

Comment: One interesting thing about this bill is that it was not introduced to legislate on what the value of $\pi$ should be (an easy way to misunderstand the story), but rather in order to copyright of a method to square the circle for exclusive use free of charge by the State of Indiana. What the legislature thought they could use this for escapes me.

Comment: Apparently (according to Wikipedia) Goodwin had also proven such "truths" as trisecting a given angle, and had them published in American Mathematical Monthly, with the disclaimer 'published by request of the author.'  Although this happened in the late 1800s, it makes me skeptical of ALL published mathematical results...

Answer (score 16):

In his book *Everybody for Everybody*, Samual A. Nigro argues that Gödel's theorems not only cast doubt on the theory of evolution, but **prove** the doctrine of original sin, the need for sacrament and penance, and that there is a future eternity.

[image]

Answer (score 15):

This is a wonderful and fascinating still life by Juan Sanchez Cotán: https://www.khanacademy.org/humanities/monarchy-enlightenment/baroque-art1/spain/a/juan-sanchez-de-cotn-quince-melon-and-cucumber

It is thought by many art historians that Cotán used a mathematical formula to determine the heights at which the various items would appear. For all I know this may be the case -- it would seem only appropriate given the name of the artist -- but I once read part of a book by a very respectable art historian (whose name I have maddeningly forgotten but I'm working on it) who said what the formula was. His evidence was just the picture itself and not any surviving record of how it was painted. But of course, given that the heights of the items are not precisely determined (anything like), it is clear that any number of curves could be declared to fit. This is not exactly misuse of a theorem but it was certainly misuse of mathematics, similar to finding the golden ratio everywhere but a bit more sophisticated.

**Added:** I've tracked it down now. The critic is Norman Bryson and he says this: "In relation to the quince, the cabbage appears to come forward slightly; the melon is further forward than the quince, the melon slice projects out beyond the ledge, and the cucumber overhangs it still further. The arc is therefore not on the same plane as its co-ordinates, it curves in three dimensions: it is a true hyperbola, of the type produced when a cone is viewed in oblique section." I haven't found more of the quotation, but I seem to remember that it was quite important to Bryson that it really was a hyperbola and not, say, an exponential decay. (As a matter of fact, looking at the picture again I am not convinced that the items form a nice curve of any kind: the cabbage is too far to the left and too near to being directly under the apple. And the relationship of the string of the cabbage with the leaves of the apple leads me to doubt whether the curve lies in an oblique plane, or indeed any plane, as he suggests.)

Comment: Heard in high-school History class, no reference unfortunately: in the early 20th century, someone published a monograph on the dimensions of a certain small building; derived many important constants from basic operations on said dimensions, showing the intent of the architects. The building in question was... ...a public urinal! 

Answer (score 14):

Sokal once again, with Brown and Friedman, wrote this paper:
The complex dynamics of wishful thinking: The critical positivity ratio [(arXiv version)](http://arxiv.org/abs/1307.7006). The story behind this is that Nick Brown, "who began a part-time psychology course in his 50s – and ended up taking on America's academic establishment" according to Andrew Anthony in the guardian http://www.theguardian.com/science/2014/jan/19/mathematics-of-happiness-debunked-nick-brown.

Answer (score 13):

In order to baffle the uninitiated, some authors interpret Banach-Tarski
paradox (stating that "it is possible to decompose a ball into five
pieces which can be reassembled by rigid motions to form two balls of
the same size as the original.", cf.
http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Banach-TarskiParadox.html) in an
obviously false way as if it could be applied to physical
objects. E.g. Reuben Hersh writes (Reuben Hersh: "What Is
Mathematics, Really?" p.255):

"Stefan Banach and Alfred Tarski proved, using the axiom of choice,
that it's possible to divide a pea (or a grape or a marshmallow) into
5 pieces such that the pieces can be moved around (translated and
rotated) to have volume greater than the sun."

Clearly, this formulation is very much misleading, since it suggests
that the paradox can be applied to a physical objects, which is
obviously false. Indeed, the construction is such that the ball is
divided into non-measurable parts and, clearly, there is no physical
objects corresponding to non-measurable sets.

Comment: Why is it clear that there are no physical objects corresponding to non-measurable sets? For the same reason that "Hilbert Space" is a purely abstract mathematical construct with no utility in physics? Oh, wait...

Comment: The quotation from Hirsch also mixes two versions of the Banach-Taski theorem.  The number 5 of pieces is, if I remember correctly, for making two balls the same size as the original.  To get from a pea to the sun, more pieces would be needed (but still only finitely many).   

Comment: I'm really bothered by the wording "applying the theorem to physical objects": a theorem is a mathematical statement, it can be applied to a mathematical object in the course of a proof, but talking about applying it to physical objects does not even begin to make sense. 

Comment: @IgorRivin: Because there is no *constructive* way of building a non-measurable set.

Answer (score 13):

I submit, for your consideration, the paper *[The structure of the world from pure numbers](http://dauns01.math.tulane.edu/~tipler/theoryofeverything.pdf)* by Frank Tipler, Professor at Tulane University (originally titled *Theory of Everything based on Feynman-Weinberg Quantum Gravity and the Extended Standard Model*). The paper was published in the peer-reviewed Reports on Progress in Physics, volume **68** (2005), pages 897-964 (doi:[10.1088/0034-4885/68/4/R04](https://doi.org/10.1088/0034-4885/68/4/R04)). Tipler's book "The Physics of Christianity" is based on this paper.

Tipler invokes Gödel's theorem (see p. 905 onwards), Presburger arithmetic,  Löwenheim-Skolem, Hales' proof of the Kepler conjecture (the latter only as an example, I believe), and various other mathematical results.

Comment: Wow, do you think he's making a bid for the Templeton Prize?

Comment: If he does, it's a slam dunk.

Comment: I had to edit this again because Tulane haven't got https set up correctly.

Answer (score 11):

This could be an unfair example, since I don't know the text myself. All I can say is that my skepticism is aroused just by the title of

- Guerino Mazzola, The Topos of Music: Geometric Logic of Concepts, Theory, and Performance (Birkhäuser, 2002)

(in other words, topos theory applied to music theory). At least one MO participant at MO (Mikael Vejdemo Johansson) has tried to read this book and came away feeling skeptical, according to his remarks [here](http://golem.ph.utexas.edu/category/2009/05/the_mathematics_of_music_at_ch.html#c024177). I'd be interested in hearing other reactions from people who have taken a stab at it.

Comment: I waited a while to say something on this as I do not really feel qualified, but as nobody else said anything so far: in view of other,  traditional, mathematical work of the author, it seems highly likely to me that if this deserves to be on the list at all then only in the category 'math is solid, but for some reason inapplicable/not relevant to the application.' Now, whether the latter is the case or not is perhaps hard to tell as (I assume) 'theory of music' is not a 'hard' subject with a clear right or wrong. Based on a talk I heard years ago I remember that using this theory one... 

Comment: ...can make concrete assertions. Specifically (the details I remember are vague and my general musical is insufficient) there was some investigation carried out whether a certain sequence A of notes constitutes the motif (in the musical sense of a certain well-known piece of music) or whether it is a sequence A'. Using this theory an anwer was given; somebody with a music background in the audience disagreed with this answer, but it was my understanding that regarding this question there is debate in the music comm., I guess somebody else might have agreed. So, not sure what this tells.  

Comment: Thanks, unknown. I would love to get my hands on the book, even if my knowledge of music is not up to the task of deciding whether this is a worthwhile investigation. I am not challenging the mathematical competence of the author, by the way. Hopefully Mikael will see this sometime and share some of his thoughts on the subject (he wrote a review that was rejected for being overly harsh, even if admired within the publishing office). 

Comment: You might find the book on the internet...

Comment: Thanks, Michael. In fact, someone I know sent me an internet copy. 

Answer (score 11):

The whole "transformation" and "network centric warfare" push in the US Department of Defense last decade under [Cebrowski](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arthur_K._Cebrowski) and Rumsfeld invoked a heap of dubious interpretations and purported applications of nonlinear phenomena (perhaps most notably when 9/11 was referred to as a "system perturbation"). See [here](http://www.seanlawson.net/?p=772) for an introductory overview.

Answer (score 11):

I call your attention to http://www.abarim-publications.com where you will find the book, Quantum Mechanics for Beginners; an Introduction with the blurb,

Quantum Mechanics studies the peculiar world of the "ones"; those things in nature that can not be divided. Since God is a One, and the Body of Christ as well, it shouldn't be surprising that the Bible discusses the "ones" at length, and this a few millennia before the emergence of Quantum Mechanics in the scientific arena. To appreciate this unexpected dimension of the Bible, Abarim Publication's fun-filled crash course in Quantum Mechanics should be mandatory at every seminary.

Also, Chaos Theory for Beginners; an Introduction:

Chaos Theory looks at patterns and their reoccurrence in nature. Since Moses built the tabernacle - which would turn into the temple, and later still in the Body of Christ - after patterns he saw in heaven, Chaos Theory is a must for every serious student of the Bible.

One of the chapters is entitled, Agape and Gravity Live Together in Perfect Harmony. Fans of Stevie Wonder may see a pun there. There is also Scripture Theory for Beginners; an Introduction:

What Chaos Theory does with nature, Scripture Theory does with Scriptures: the identification of reoccurring patterns and their meanings. Especially interesting are those Biblical patterns that are identical to those found in high-energy physics.

Answer (score 10):

Not really a theorem but amusing non-sense. Somebody (it was perhaps Sokal) told me about a psychanalytical book based on set theory. The author wrote it in English and translated
the french terminology "th\'eorie des ensembles" as "Theory of the (w)hole". The book was later translated into French with the title "Th\'eorie des t(r)ous".

Answer (score 8):

It's physics rather than math, but surely [this creative paper](http://www.physics.nyu.edu/sokal/transgress_v2/transgress_v2_singlefile.html) by Alan Sokal deserves mention.

Comment: See also http://www.physics.nyu.edu/sokal/lingua_franca_v4/lingua_franca_v4.html.

Answer (score 8):

A rare instance of Gödel-abuse in a published paper is "[Bacterial wisdom, Gödel's theorem and creative genomic webs](http://star.tau.ac.il/~eshel/papers/bacterial%2520wisdom.pdf)" by Eshel Ben-Jacob. Here, Gödel's theorem is used to prove that "a system cannot self-design another system which is more advanced than itself", with application to genomics.

Answer (score 7):

[This is my favourite example.](http://www.emergentpublications.com/ECO/submissions/manuscript_37.pdf?AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1)

From the text:

> The Mandelbrot set provides a fractal representation of how these
>   unique individuals provide self-similarity within the larger intrinsic
>   case. This theme, in particular, focuses on how these individuals’
>   experiences with change contribute to the overall stress within the
>   larger far-from-equilibrium system

Authors try to analyze how librarians work, by making an analogy with fractals.
Also, the obligatory reference to Heisenbergs uncertainty principle.

Answer (score 7):

[Here](https://davidrivesministries.org/fractals-gods-beauty-in-numbers/) we read,

Dr. Jason Lisle provides “a little window into the mind of God” by exploring the amazingly beautiful and complex secret code that God has built into numbers. Using fractals – types of structures that repeat infinitely on smaller and smaller scales – Dr. Lisle demonstrates that the laws of math couldn’t possibly have resulted from any kind of evolution and could only have originated from God. Fractals have no reasonable explanation in the secular/evolutionary worldview, but their intricacy, complexity, and wondrous beauty reflect the infinitely complex and inexpressibly powerful mind of the Creator.

Answer (score 6):

Russian media provide a lot of amusing examples. Let me mention two:

1) (Perelman's proof of) the Poincaré conjecture leads to understanding the shape of the Universe;

2) (this is maybe what you mean in the post) it follows from the Godel's theorem that God does not exist.

Comment: I'm not altogether convinced by your first example: see http://mathoverflow.net/questions/9708/poincare-conjecture-and-the-shape-of-the-universe

Comment: As you probably know, Godel actually gave an "ontological proof" of the existence of God, although unrelated to incompleteness.

Answer (score 5):

In the same vein as the bayesian argument for creationism and misapplications of Gödel's incompleteness theorems, there are misapplications of the second law of thermodynamics against evolution of life ("undesigned", e.g. darwinian or lamarckian).

The second law is a mathematical consequence of Hamilton and Schrödinger equations for reasonable hamiltonians, in particular of fundamental physical evolution equations, and also of simple statistical models (statistical ensembles).
See [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_law_of_thermodynamics#Derivation_from_statistical_mechanics).

The argument is that life is complex and evolution implies a decrease in entropy/increase in complexity contradicting the second law. See for instance [here](http://www.christiananswers.net/q-eden/edn-thermodynamics.html).

The flaw is that the Earth, where evolution occurs, is not an isolated system. If we consider rather the solar (or just Sun-Earth) system there is loss of entropy on Earth but a compensating gain on the Sun.

For a recent anecdote (and a nice blog to add to your blogroll) see [Retraction Watch](http://retractionwatch.wordpress.com/2011/03/16/more-on-applied-mathematical-letters-journal-retracted-paper-questioning-second-law-of-thermodynamics/).

Answer (score 5):

I recently came across a paper of **P. Cirillo and N. N. Taleb**, ”On the statistical properties and tail risk of violent conflicts”, which purports to disprove a widely cited claim by Steven Pinker that violence has decreased over time, but, interestingly enough, is published in a physics journal.

A highlight on paper’s webpage states that the paper provides a new method for dealing with ”heavy-tailed but bounded random variables”.

The key point of the ”method” is to apply to the data the transform
$$
φ(Y)=L−H\cdot \log\left(\frac{H−Y}{H-L}\right),
$$
where $H$ is the current population of Earth, taken to be 7 billion , $Y$ the number of casualities in a conflict, historically never greater than 100 million, and $L$ is a lower cut-of for $Y$, taken to be 3000. I hope everyone here can check that in fact
$$
\varphi(Y)=Y\cdot (1\pm 0.001),
$$
in other words, given the accuracy of historic data on casualities, the transform $\varphi$ does not transform anything at all.

The whole paper, of course, just a bunch of buzz-words the authors have no idea about. But it also raises a question: if the authors have actually looked at the data and applied their transform, how could they not notice that it does nothing?

Answer (score 4):

This reference is an excellent parody of the so-called application of mathematics to economics and other social sciences (it purports to apply mathematics to theology):
http://www.amazon.de/corruptionis-Entscheidungslogische-Ein%C3%BCbungen-H%C3%B6here-Amoralit%C3%A4t/dp/3922305016

Answer (score 3):

I just came across the paper [BAK-SNEPPEN MODELS FOR THE EVOLUTION OF STRUCTURED KNOWLEDGE](http://journals.ru.lv/index.php/SIE/article/view/1543) in *SOCIETY. INTEGRATION. EDUCATION
Proceedings of the International Scientific Conference*.

The abstract states:

> Models of biological evolution can help to understand many social and economical phenomena where the search for optimality is hindered by voluntary or random competition. Bak-Sneppen is one of the most significant models because it balances at best explication power and simplicity. Unlike cellular automata models, Bak-Sneppen models join locality and globality. The authors try to re-read these models in the framework of mathematics, where, despite its high developped structure, knowledge waves can hinder comprehension both of pupils and of scholars.

Answer (score 0):

[Copying an answer I posted to another question [over here](https://www.quora.com/Can-physics-and-mathematics-explain-God-and-the-supernatural/answer/Noam-Zeilberger). I think these are actually nice examples of scientists taking pains *not* to misapply science to theology, although Mendeleev still argues for the immortality of the soul by analogy from conservation laws in physics.]

Once, browsing in the local history section of the Central Library in Rochester, NY, I stumbled upon a curious book:
[image]

The book (a full scan of which is available [here](https://archive.org/details/proofsoflifeafte01thom)) is a collection of responses by various thoughtful people to the following request:

> Dear Sir:
>
> The Author of this letter, inspired by the untimely decease of a dear friend, and in contemplation of the numerous philosophical and logical theories leading to a belief in the continued existence of the soul, or personal identity after death, begs of you the great favor of a letter, setting out as briefly, or at such length as may be convenient, what you consider to be the strongest reason, or argument, advanced by science or philosophy, or by common sense, in favor of an affirmative answer to this mighty question; or preferably, a statement of your own deductions thereon.
>
> It is our desire to obtain from thinkers and educators of the world, an expression—a twentieth century bulletin, on this subject.
>
> Our request will impress you doubtless as an unusual one, but none the less will you see the force of it, and its possibilities. Who can measure the impetus such a compilation may have upon the inquiring human mind?
>
> May I not have your co-operation in this matter?
>
> Thanking you now in advance for the courtesy of a reply, I am
>
> Fraternally yours,
> ROBERT J. THOMPSON.
>
> Wellington Ave., Chicago, U. S. A.
> October, 1901.

I had fun skimming through the first collection of responses, from "The Scientists". The variety of responses is interesting. Although there's the usual bloviation on the cosmological and teleological arguments, as well as some self-citations to studies confirming the existence of telepathy and other paranormal phenomena, there's also some healthy scientific modesty. E.g., [E. Ducleaux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%89mile_Duclaux) writes,

> Excuse me for not being able to help you in your investigation. I have no scientific opinion regarding the questions you put. I mean, no opinion that rests on anything but personal beliefs. Besides, I think that everybody is in about the same position and that any reasons that may be brought forth in favor of one's opinion are only good for the person that brings them forth, and that they cannot impress the listener; they are therefore not scientific reasons.

[D. I. Mendélieff](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dmitri_Mendeleev)'s response begins similarly, although he ends by arguing for the immortality of the soul by analogy with the laws of conservation of mass and energy (an analogy I was surprised to see repeated very often in other responses!):

> The question as to the continuance of the existence of the soul or personal identity after death, mentioned in your letter of August, 1901, I, as a natural philosopher, consider to be an hypothesis which cannot be proved by evidence of real facts. But as a man educated in a religious sense, I prefer to remain in the belief of the immortality of the soul. It is my opinion that the philosophical side of the question consists in the relation between the soul, the natural forces, and matter; and if it were possible to clear up to some extent this feature of the problem---the relation between force and matter---then also the relation between the soul and natural forces would be forwarded to a great extent.
>
> The unquestionable existence of reason, will and consciousness compels us to acknowledge the existence of a special world of relations of this kind, and any rational conclusion in relation to this special world cannot be accepted as proved quite in the same manner. Knowledge of physics and mechanics does not give anything in relation to chemistry or in relation to the existence of celestial bodies.
>
> We must simply confess that it is impossible to comprehend this question in a general way, but it would also be sheer nonsense to ignore the physical world; and as matter and natural forces must be acknowledged as eternal, it is also probable that the soul is eternal.

But my favorite response was by James R. Nichols, marveling at the modern-day wonders of technology and anticipating the next version of the iPhone:

> Do we not every day converse with unseen friends long distances away; do we not recognize their familiar voices, in homes separated from us by rivers, woods, and mountains? These voices come out of the darkness, guided by a frail wire which science provides as a pathway.
>
> [...]
>
> If our friends in this life, dead to us (hidden as they are by the shroud of space), can be seen, and we can hear their voices, their shouts of laughter, the words of the hymns they sing, the cries of the little ones in the mother's arms, is it very absurd to anticipate a time when those dead to us by the dissolution of the body may, by some unknown telephony, send to us voices from a realm close at hand, but hidden from mortal vision?