# Unreasonable application of mathematics to the other areas

Tags: reference-request, ho.history-overview, mathematical-philosophy

What are some papers or talks on the philosophy of  mathematics which contains some statements  about the unnecessary and unreasonable application of  mathematics in other areas of  science?

I found one paper as follows page 515, the last  paragraph(before the discussion)

http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0315086075901135.

I search for  some more references.Your answer is very  appreciated.

Edit:  Our  question is   a  particular case of the  following post. However our post is  motivated by a  philosophical paper of [Bishop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Errett_Bishop), a paper which we  cited it in this our post but it  is  not cited in the following post

[Examples of theorems misapplied to non-mathematical contexts](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/61408/examples-of-theorems-misapplied-to-non-mathematical-contexts)

Comment: This question is a possible duplicate of: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/61408/examples-of-theorems-misapplied-to-non-mathematical-contexts

Comment: The following are highly relevant, discussions between Karl Egil Aubert and nobel prize winner simons:  http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF03023736#page-1    , references in http://web.unitn.it/files/8_03_vela.pdf   (and its section "he Unreasonable Ineffectiveness of Mathematics in Economics")

Comment: [Fashionable Nonsense](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fashionable_Nonsense) is a book by Sokal and Bricmont that lampoons modern philosophy for trying to use mathematics (or at least, mathematical language) without understanding it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One of the earliest contributions along this line is from Goethe, [Über Mathematik und deren Mißbrauch](https://books.google.nl/books?id=LHAHAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA167&lpg=PA167&dq=uber+mathematik+und+deren+missbrauch+goethe&source=bl&ots=4uE3j5NieH&sig=YVag1aSPp5D8lVRefPEi-BUQS8A&hl=nl&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q&f=false) (1826). When describing the abuse (Mißbrauch) in the applications of mathematics to the natural world, in particular the perception of color, Goethe laments that: *"Mathematicians are like Frenchmen; if one speaks to them they translate it into their own language, and then it will be very soon something entirely different."* Still, Goethe stresses that "*I have heard myself accused of being an opponent, an enemy of mathematics, which no one can value more highly than I, for it accomplishes the very thing whose achievement has been denied me.*"

Comment: . . . for 45 minutes and nobody understood a word that he said . . .

Comment: Alice’s Restaurant?

Comment: Although I have a lot of difficulty reading German (all the more when it's written in Gothic script), I was unable to locate in that text the quote "Die Mathematiker sind eine Art Franzosen; redet man zu ihnen, so übersetzen sie es in ihre Sprache, und dann ist es alsobald ganz etwas anders." Is there a page number you can point me to?

Comment: (In Maximen und Reflexionen, page 266 here: https://books.google.com/books?id=xyoEAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA266&lpg=PA266&dq=Die+Mathematiker+sind+eine+Art+Franzosen;+redet+man+zu+ihnen,+so+%C3%BCbersetzen+sie+es+in+ihre+Sprache,+und+dann+ist+es+alsobald+ganz+etwas+anders.&source=bl&ots=hHyXCcm8lw&sig=4jhtvY9rNPbs14Hx9W605CD24q8&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj59YaRscjNAhUMdz4KHeslCIEQ6AEIVjAI#v=onepage&q=Die%20Mathematiker%20sind%20eine%20Art%20Franzosen%3B%20redet%20man%20zu%20ihnen%2C%20so%20%C3%BCbersetzen%20sie%20es%20in%20ihre%20Sprache%2C%20und%20dann%20ist%20es%20alsobald%20ganz%20etwas%20anders.&f=false)

Comment: @ToddTrimble --- I stand corrected, it's definitely a Goethe quote, but not from the "Mißbrauch" text.

Comment: @CarloBeenakker  thank you for your answer. Many years ago, I found the quote about mathematicians and French men in the book differential topology by M. Hirsch(At the head of a chapter

Comment: @CarloBeenakker  Chapter 7 of that book "Cobordism".

Answer (score 3):

It's a not a paper or a talk, but a book, but I think it's thematically fitting: *Gödel's Theorem: An Incomplete Guide to Its Use and Abuse* by Torkel Franzén.

Here's a quote from the review http://www.ams.org/notices/200703/rev-raatikainen.pdf

> Apparently no mathematical theorem has aroused as much interest outside mathematics as Kurt Gödel’s celebrated [incompleteness result](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%B6del%27s_incompleteness_theorems) published in 1931. It is invoked not only by mathematicians, logicians, and philosophers but also by physicists, theologians, literary critics, archi- tects, and others. Some eminent physicists have interpreted it as showing that “the theory of everything” demanded by other physicists is impossible to achieve. It is sometimes claimed to prove the existence of God or of free will, the necessary incompleteness of the Bible or of the U.S. Constitution, or the impossibility of genuine knowledge in mathematics—just to mention a few of the many alleged applications.